# What is the meaning of ":" in this TypeScript code?

Tags: typescript, observable

I can't understand what is the meaning of second `:` in this code:

```
  getDish(id: number): Observable<Dish> {
    return  this.restangular.one('dishes',id).get();
  }
```

I know the first `:` means id has the type number, and it is the input argument of `getDish()` function. But what do does the second `:` do? Is it the output type of the `getDish()` function and means the output is an object of `Dish` class with the `Observable` type?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means; the return value of the function is an `Observable` of a `Dish`. Why did you think otherwise? Did you read http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the explaination below

```
id: number <-- type of the id variable is number
getDish(id: number): Observable<Dish> <-- the return value of the function i GetDish is of type Observable<Dish>
```